# How to check valid bson object id - Elixir?

Tags: mongodb, elixir

I want to validate `bson_id` is valid or not,  in the url like `http://localhost/users/590ffa5c421aa91ece8bec0/show`, what is the best way to check that in `elixir` ?

Comment: So 24 hex characters? like this: `"590ffa5c421aa91ece8bec0f" =~ ~r/^[0-9a-f]{24}$/ #=> true`?

Comment: @Dogbert thanks man its working correcly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match 24 hex digits with the regular expression `^[0-9a-f]{24}$`:

```
iex(1)> "590ffa5c421aa91ece8bec0f" =~ ~r/^[0-9a-f]{24}$/
true
iex(2)> "590ffa5c421aa91ece8bec0" =~ ~r/^[0-9a-f]{24}$/
false
iex(3)> "590ffa5c421aa91ece8bec0z" =~ ~r/^[0-9a-f]{24}$/
false
```